# Searching for strings with double quotes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out all rows that have a double quotes character in a particular field.

I am trying something like `charindex(columnname,'""')` in the `where` clause, but it does not seem to work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: tried `select * from %tablename% where %columnname% like '%"%'`?

Comment: why don't you try `like` operator?

Comment: user5226582 answer is totally valid. If you want to use programming instead database, you can do: 
charindex ($col, '&quot;&quot;');
or you can try &#34; (HTML number of ") instead &quot; (HTML name of ")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is only one double quote then you should try

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%"%'
```

If you know that there are two consecutive double quotes then, I would suggest you to use a like statement

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%""%'
```

Otherwise if you don't know then you should try(Which is more preferable)

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%"%"%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE col Like '%"%'
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE CHARINDEX('"',col) > 0
```